# How to prevent pagination reset in datatable using global configuration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to stay on the same page of datatables after data changes when the table is reloaded? I've managed to persist datatable state after page refresh globally using

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "bStateSave": true,
```

in `plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js`. BTW, is it a good solution to modify the code of the plugin itself?

But the datatable keeps resetting after I modify any row.
Then I've managed to persist the page using `table.ajax.reload(null, false)`.
My goal is to apply this behaviour globally in the project without modifying each of the pages (there are about 700 occurences of `table.ajax.reload()` in the project). Adding

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable, {
  "ajax": {
      "reload": {
          "callback": null,
          "resetPaging": false
        }
    }
});
```

in `plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js` haven't done the trick.

Comment: Not an answer, just some notes: (1) You could [edit the source](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L7658) and change `resetPaging===false` to `resetPaging===true`. That is risky because it silently changes the core behavior, and it can easily be lost when DataTables is upgraded and the modification is forgotten about.

Comment: (2) You could override the existing `ajax.reload()` function using [`$.fn.dataTable.Api.register()`](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/api#Registering-a-new-method) - but that will get messy because `ajax.reload()` depends on other local variables in the core library - which will not be directly accessible to your code. Finally: (3) It sounds like you want to avoid doing this (which I understand!), but why not do a global search-and-replace from `ajax.reload()` to `ajax.reload(null, false)`?

Comment: @andrewJames the source for this plugin is minified js. Looks like this `r("ajax.reload()",function(a,b){return this.iterator("table",function(c){Pb(c,!1===b,a)})});`. Tried to replace `!1===b` with `false` with no luck.